# Cant input numbers into mtarix. why index goes out of range?

Tags: python-2.7

Cant input numbers in matrix.Why I get IndexError: list assignment index out of range?

```
i, j = 5, 7;
matrix = [[x + y for x in xrange(i)] for y in xrange(j)]
print (matrix)
for w in xrange(i):
    print (w)
    for h in xrange(j):
        tmp = int(input('Enter element of matrix'))
        matrix[w][h] = tmp
sums = map( lambda row: sum(row), matrix)
print (matrix)
print (sums)
print ('max:', sums.index(max(sums)))
print ('min:', sums.index(min(sums)))
```

Comment: `i` is the inner indice. Just swap i & j either at init or in the loop.

Comment: Ok. that was easier then i thought :D

Comment: also: `lambda row: sum(row)` => `sum` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix = [[x + y for x in xrange(i)] for y in xrange(j)]
```

The above line makes the number of columns = i and rows = j, because it will create a j lists with i variables where each list acts as a row.

```
for w in xrange(i):
print (w)
for h in xrange(j):
    tmp = int(input('Enter element of matrix'))
    matrix[w][h] = tmp
```

and in this loop you are using w as rows which is ranging from 0 to i-1 instead it should be 0 to j-1 
similarly  h should range from 0 to i-1 not 0 to j-1
so your loop should be like this -

```
for w in xrange(j):  #note this changed from i to j
print (w)
for h in xrange(i):  #and this from j to i
    tmp = int(input('Enter element of matrix'))
    matrix[w][h] = tmp
```